# image caching. Selectively load images from cache and remote storage

Tags: image, caching, resources, flash

we develop huge game and it takes some time to load on startup because of tons of assets. Once per week or 2 weeks it is updated to new version which might bring few new assets or update previous ones.
So now we are trying to find the way that will allow flash to load only new/updated assets and the rest to fetch from cache. But we haven't succeeded yet. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Flash relies on the browser to fetch assets and everything else you might download. Any strategies  that people are using to manage how the browser caches stuff should also work for Flash. I'm on a mobile device, so I can't help much more right now.

Comment: you took me wrong. I don't care about whether an image is in cache. Rough example:
assume the cache is clear, now application started and downloads images 1 and 2 from a storage, if the page is refreshed those 1 and 2 images will be fetched from cache. Now new version of game is coming and the 2 image is updated and 3 image is added. The 3 image is not in cache so it's downloaded automatically from storage but the 2 image is IN cache and will be fetched from there by normal loading unless a timestamp is used for example. So I need to make sure the updated images will NOT be taken from cache.

Comment: How to figure it out? Using a proper timestamp? By images renaming? Sending to client the list of updated images?